# Hive Partitions repair failing with Hive 2.0

Tags: hive, partition, repair

With release of Hive 2.0, MSCK Repair Table doesn't work. It failed most of the times or hung forever. Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: a hourly partition table, 3 year data.  5 * 365 *24 = 26k partitions. it takes about 90 minutes . maybe it's just need more time .